# ASP.NET MVC 5 Web App Slow Performance with MySQL database and NHibernate

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 App with MySQL which is hosted on a VPS having 32GB RAM and Quad Core Processor. This is the only app on this VPS.

I have tried many ways to improve the performance. Like

1. Database Indexing
2. Pagination
3. Have tried to make the requests lightweight.

But I am still struggling with the load time of data. Data is taking too much time. Even fetch operations having less than 5000 entries take minutes.

I am using NHibernate as an ORM.

Any NHibernate expert around? who can list down a few suggestions to speed up the fetch operations?

Comment: Use the [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) to determine the slowest type of query.  Then present it here, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: does it start slow or is it increasing over time?